# Is it possible to change only the alpha of a rgba background colour on hover?

Tags: css, hover, background-color, rgba

I have a set of `<a>` tags with differing rgba background colours but the same alpha. Is it possible to write a single css style that will change only the opacity of the rgba attribute?

A quick example of the code:

```
 <a href="#"><img src="" /><div class="brown">Link 1</div></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="" /><div class="green">Link 2</div></a>
```

And the styles

```
a {display: block; position: relative}
.brown {position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(118,76,41,.8);}
.green {position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(51,91,11,.8);}
```

What I would like to do is write a single style that would change the opacity when the `<a>` is hovered over, yet keep the colour unchanged.

Something like

```
a:hover .green, a:hover .brown {background-color: rgba(inherit,inherit,inherit,1);}
```

Comment: By the way, what are your `div` elements doing in your `a` elements?

Comment: @BoltClock [HTML5 allows block-level `a` elements.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: @mercator: Alright. I missed that.

Comment: @BoltClock It seemed the simplest way to code for the effect, a single `a` tag as opposed to one around the `img` and another around the text. The fact that it's supported by HTML 5 is a nice bonus.

Comment: When this question was asked - this wasn't possible with CSS. Now this **is possible** - with [CSS Variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/) - as I've shown in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463603/703717)

Comment: Here's a link for those wondering how to [convert RGB to RGBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6672374).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is now possible with custom properties:

```
.brown { --rgb: 118, 76, 41; }
.green { --rgb: 51, 91, 11; }

a { display: block; position: relative; }
div { position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), 0.8); }
a:hover div { background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), 1); }
```

To understand how this works, see [How do I apply opacity to a CSS color variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010597/how-do-i-apply-opacity-to-a-css-color-variable/41265350#41265350)

If custom properties are not an option, see the original answer below.

---

Unfortunately, no, you'll have to specify the red, green and blue values again for each individual class:

```
a { display: block; position: relative; }

.brown { position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(118, 76, 41, 0.8); }
a:hover .brown { background-color: rgba(118, 76, 41, 1); }

.green { position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(51, 91, 11, 0.8); }
a:hover .green { background-color: rgba(51, 91, 11, 1); }
```

You can only use the `inherit` keyword alone as a value for the property, and even then the use of `inherit` isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Eagerly waiting for color modification functions (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/) so we don't have to define the color channels as a list.

Answer (score 18):

You could do various things to avoid having to hard code the numbers if you want to. Some of these methods only work if you use a plain white background as they're really adding white on top rather than reducing opacity. The first one should work fine for everything provided:

- you aren't already using the psuedo-element for something; and
- you can set `position` to relative or absolute on the `<div>` tag

#### Option 1: `::before` psuedo-element:

```
.before_method{
  position:relative;
}
.before_method:before{
  display:block;
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background:rgb(18, 176, 41);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  opacity:0.5;
}
.before_method:hover:before{
  opacity:1;
}
```

#### Option 2: white gif overlay:

```
.image_method{
  background-color: rgb(118, 76, 41);
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Translucent_50_percent_white.png)
}
.image_method:hover{
  background-image:none;
}
```

#### Option 3: `box-shadow` method:

A variation of the gif method, but may have performance issues.

```
.shadow_method{
  background-color: rgb(18, 176, 41);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 99999px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
.shadow_method:hover{
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

CodePen examples: http://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/ACdka

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I found the third option useful and simpler if I reverse this method: don't use anything additional without hover, and on hover use: box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 99999px rgba(128,128,128,0.2). This was necessary for me because my rows alternate white and light gray, so the original answer didn't change the white.

Comment: Liked the shadow method a lot.

Answer (score 13):

No, it's not possible.

You could try a [CSS pre-processor](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-css-preprocessors-to-speed-up-development-time), though, if you want to do this sort of thing.

From what I could see, at least [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#-color-functions) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#opacity_functions) have functions that can make colors more, or less, transparent.

Comment: I always forget about SCSS/LESS. Always. Maybe I need to start actually using them.

Comment: In SCSS, it is transparentize([color], 0.8). See http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#transparentize-instance_method

Answer (score 9):

It's now 2017 and this is now possible with

### [CSS custom properties / CSS Variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/) ([Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables))

One classic use case for CSS variables is the ability to individualize parts of a property's value.

So here, instead of repeating the whole rgba expression once again -
we split up or 'individulaize' the `rgba` values into 2 parts / variables  (one for the rgb value and one for the alpha)

```
.brown { 
  --rgb: 118, 76, 41; 
}
.green {
  --rgb: 51, 91, 11;
}
.brown, .green {
  --alpha: 0.3;
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), var(--alpha));
}
```

Then, on hover we can now just modify the --alpha variable:

```
a:hover .green, a:hover .brown {
  --alpha: 1;
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.brown { 
  --rgb: 118, 76, 41; 
}
.green {
  --rgb: 51, 91, 11;
}
.brown, .green {
  display: inline-block;
  --alpha: 0.3;
  background-color: rgba(var(--rgb), var(--alpha));
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
}

a:hover .green, a:hover .brown {
  --alpha: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="brown">Link 1</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="green">Link 2</div>
</a>
```

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/vJXBmw?editors=1100)

### Further reading:

[Individualizing CSS Properties with CSS Variables (Dan Wilson)](http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2017/04/individualized-properties/)

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not possible.

If you want to use `rgba`, you must set each value together. There's no way to only change the alpha.

Answer (score 6):

there is an alternative,you can add a linear-gradient background image onto the original color.

```
a{
  background: green
}
a:hover{
  background-image:linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,0%,.2) 100%,transparent 100%) // darker
}
a:hover{
  background-image:linear-gradient(hsla(255,100%,100%,.2) 100%,transparent 100%) // lighter
}
```

also, with css3 filter property,you can do that too,but it seems that it will change the text color

```
a:hover{
   filter: brightness(80%) //darker
}
a:hover{
   filter: brightness(120%) //lighter
}
```

here is a jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zhangyu911013/epwyL296/2/

Comment: so far the only satisfying answer for me.

Comment: Agree with Andre.  Can be further simplified with use of css variables.  Have added an answer to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `:hover` and specify a different opacity in the hover class?

```
a:hover {
     opacity:0.6
}
```

Comment: Because that affects the whole element.

Comment: with SVG objects, it's possible to use [`fill-opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity)

Comment: not only the whole element, but all child elements as well.

Comment: Not perfect perhaps, but it is useful for some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I had 18 different divs working as buttons, and each with a different color. Rather than figure out the color codes for each or use a div:hover selector to change the opacity (which affects all children) I used the pseudo-class :before like in @Chris Boon's answer.

Because I wanted to do the coloring on the individual elements, I used :before to create a transparent white div on :hover. This is a very basic washout.

```
#categories div {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
}

#categories div:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#categories div:hover:before {
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.2;
}

#a_Particular_Div {
    background-color:red;
}
```

According to CanIUse.com, this should have something like 92% support as of early 2014. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS variables, although it's a little messy.

First, set a variable containing *just* the RGB values, in order, of the color you want to use:

```
:root {
  --color-success-rgb: 80, 184, 60; 
}
```

Then you can assign an RGBA value for a color and pull everything but the alpha value from this variable:

```
.button--success {
  background: rgba(var(--color-success-rgb), 0.8);
}
```

This isn't super pretty, but it lets you use the same RGB values but different alpha values for a color.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution to the problem.  And, the variable with color doesn't have to be on `:root`, it can be on the class of element, setting its base color.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

simple solution :

```
a
{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    background: rgba(red, 0.75);
    padding: 20px;


   &:before
   {
     content: ' ';
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   &:hover
   {
     &:before
     {
       background-color: rgba(#000, 0.25); 
     }
   }
}
```

exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/epwyL296/14/

just play with alpha of background. if you want light instead of darkness, just replace #000 by #fff

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** It's not possible to do that unfortunately. You'll need to write two separate selectors of:

```
a.green:hover {background-color: rgba(118,76,41,1);}
a.brown:hover {background-color: rgba(118,76,41,1);}
```

According to the W3C, the `rgba` property doesn't have/support the `inherit` value.

Comment: The issue is that `inherit` isn't a valid function argument. You'll notice it doesn't work with any other CSS function.

Comment: By function do you mean things like `rgba` and `transitions`? Because I know it's supported with quite a few of the properties.

Comment: Yup, along with `url()`, `attr()` etc too. `inherit` is a property value only.

Comment: I knew about `url()` and transitions already. I just wasn't 100% sure on `rgba` because it's used for colours. Thank you for educating me though :)!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. Here's what I did and it works fine( `only alpha changes on hover and also the text is not affected`) by the following steps:

1) Apply a highlighted(or any of your choice) class to whichever element you wish to change background alpha of.

2) Get the background color rgba

3) Store it in a string and manipulate it(change alpha) as you want on hover(mouseenter and mouseleave)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="highlighted brown">Link 1</div><br><br>
<div class="highlighted green">Link 1</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.brown {background-color: rgba(118,76,41,.8);}
.green {background-color: rgba(51,91,11,.8);}
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).on({

            mouseenter: function() {

            var rgba_str = $(this).css("background-color");
            var new_rgba_str ="rgba(" + rgba_str.substring(rgba_str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,rgba_str.lastIndexOf(",")) + ", 0.5)";   

                $(this).css("background-color",new_rgba_str ); 
               },

             mouseleave: function(){

                 var rgba_str = $(this).css("background-color");

            var new_rgba_str ="rgba(" + rgba_str.substring(rgba_str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,rgba_str.lastIndexOf(",")) + ", 0.8)";               
                $(this).css("background-color",new_rgba_str ); 

               }

        },'.highlighted');
```

Working Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/HGHT6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround with `opacity` if you can accommodate a slight change in `background-color`:

```
.yourClass {
    // Your style here //
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.yourClass:hover, .yourClass:focus {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.yourClass:active {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.yourClass:hover, .yourClass:focus, .yourClass:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Yu Zhang's answer:

In :root, (or parent component in Blazor) set css variables:

```
--bg-img-light: linear-gradient(hsla(255,100%,100%,.2) 100%, transparent 100%);
--bg-img-dark: linear-gradient(hsla(0,0%,0%,.2) 100%, transparent 100%);
```

Then on any element that you want to apply a hover effect on:

```
.buttontomakelighter:hover {
  background-image: var(--bg-img-light);
}

.buttontomakedarker:hover {
  background-image: var(--bg-img-dark);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

This is about the simplest way; put this in your css stylesheet:

```
a:hover { color : #c00; }
```

done!

Comment: -- just match the color to something close. opacity does not work in all browsers.

Comment: Your answer has a nice trick, but your comment is totally irrelevant.