# Can I add alpha transparency to a CSS color variable?

Tags: css, colors, opacity, css-variables

In CSS3, we can create color variables. Like so:

```
:root {
  --red: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

and use it elsewhere in document. Like so:

```
.element1 {
  background: var(--red);
}
```

Now I want the `.element2`'s color to be 80% of alpha value of `--red`, normally I would do `rgba(255, 0, 0, .8)`. But now I am using color variable `--red`. Is there any way to `calc()`ulate the alpha value over `--red`? *Because I don't want to fill my CSS file with variables.*

PS: This question may seem like [How do I apply opacity to a CSS color variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40010597/939986) post, but is different because that question discusses on how to create another variable for the same.