# Converting HEX to RGBa

Tags: css, sass, hex, rgba

I want to convert HEX color in RGB, but searching on the web I understood that I can do it with SASS but only with **RGBa**.

So consider this code:

```
@mixin hex-rgba($hexcolor, $opacity) {
  background-color: rgba($hexcolor, $opacity); 
}

div {
  @include hex-rgba(#333333, .3);
}
```

It returns:

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
}
```

But if i set alpha to 1 (or 100%) it returns the hex value:

```
div {
  @include hex-rgba(#333333, 1);
}

div {
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

How can I obtain the rgba value even if alpha is 100%?

In a way like

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}
```

**SOLVED**

```
@function rgb($hexcolor){
  $red:red($hexcolor);
  $green:green($hexcolor);
  $blue:blue($hexcolor);
  $alpha:alpha($hexcolor);
  @return unquote("rgb(#{$red},#{$green},#{$blue})");
}

:root {
  --color: #{rgb(#ffffff)};
}
```

Comment: Try the updated code for Percentages

Comment: If someone provides an answer to your question, you should accept their answer instead of updating the question with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code

```
 @mixin hex-rgba($hexcolor, $opacity) {
  @if $opacity == 1 or $opacity == 100% {

  background-color:hex($hexcolor);
  }
  @else {
   background-color: rgba($hexcolor, $opacity);
  }
}


@function hex($hexcolor){
  $red:red($hexcolor);
  $green:green($hexcolor);
  $blue:blue($hexcolor);
  $alpha:alpha($hexcolor);
  @return unquote("rgba(#{$red},#{$green},#{$blue},#{$alpha})");
}

div {
  @include hex-rgba(#333333, 0.2);
}
```

**TRY THIS UPDATED CODE**

```
@function hex($hexcolor,$opacity){
  $red:red($hexcolor);
  $green:green($hexcolor);
  $blue:blue($hexcolor);
  $alpha:alpha($hexcolor);
  @if $opacity == 1 or $opacity == 100% {
    @return unquote("rgba(#{$red},#{$green},#{$blue},#{$alpha})");
  }
  @else{
    @return unquote("rgba(#{$red},#{$green},#{$blue},#{$opacity})");
  }
}

body {
  background-color:#{hex(#333333,0.5)};
}

:root {
  --color: #{hex(#ff0000,1)};
}
div{
  height:50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

[Working Fiddle For Updated Code](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/u18pfsrc/)

Also You can try on *Sassmeister*

[Working Fiddle OLD](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/nysqxvcd/8/)

[Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com)

Comment: What if I want to use the function for a CSS var declaration? https://codepen.io/acespace90/pen/zbyKNz

Comment: @antoniomatera, Please Find the updated code block. Is this what you need?

Comment: Based on your function, I tried to use with variables, but without success. Could you help with this example number "four": https://jsfiddle.net/Allan_Andrade/ws4kmyj5/20/

Comment: @AllanAndrade check this post 
https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/how-to-combine-sass-color-functions-and-css-variables

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking to switch color theme with scss.

### NEW METHOD (no need for functions or new variables.)

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951626/11685855

```
.div {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.div::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

### OLD METHOD(using function)

```
// To convert hex to RGB codes.
@function hexToRGB($hex) {

      @return red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex); // Plain comma seperated RGB values.
     
}

$body-color: #fefbfb; // Light Theme
$body-color-d: #0f111a; // Dark Theme

:root {
  --body-color-rgb: #{hexToRGB($body-color)}; // Calling 
}

body.dark{
  --body-color: #{$body-color-d};
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.div {
  background-color: rgba(var(--body-color-rgb), 0.9);
}
```

Credits: https://medium.com/techhive-io/how-to-use-css-variables-with-sass-mixins-671e1f6067b3

Summary: Alpha doesnt work with root hex variables in rgba. Eg: rgba(var(--body-color) ,1)
but rgba(#fefbfb, 1) does. But theme switching isn't possible this way.
Read the above article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only RGB, try to use this

```
@function toRGB ($color) {
    @return "rgb(" + red($color) + ", " + green($color) + ", " + blue($color)+ ")";
}

color: toRGB(#ffffff); /* returns color: rgb(255, 255, 255)*/
```

Comment: This looks good but what if I want to use this function for css var? See here https://codepen.io/acespace90/pen/zbyKxN

Comment: Why would you like to use CSS variables when you can use variables from SASS ? All you have to do is: `$primary: toRGB(#ffffff);` and then for example `background: $primary`

Comment: because i want to switch color theme of my web app ;-)