# Using CSS vars in SCSS throws syntax error (SASS Live Compiler)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm trying to apply CSS variables to my RBG/RGBA but my VS Code Live SASS compiler throws a syntax error telling me I did not provide adequate arguments. Is there a work around for this?

**CSS**

```
:root {
    --bg-color: 50, 50, 50, 0.5;
}

.container {
    background: rgba(var(--bg-color));
}
```

**VS Code Live SASS Compilation error:**

```
--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: overloaded function `rgba` given wrong number of arguments
        on line 329 of sass/.../main.scss
>>             background: rgba(var(--bg-color));
   ------------------------^

--------------------
```

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010597/how-do-i-apply-opacity-to-a-css-color-variable/41265350. The opacity is rendered outside the rgb declarations parens. Which in this case might mean one variable for the rgb and another for the alpha percentage.

Comment: I have the same issue if I just use RGB. There seems to be no way to tell VS Code Live SASS Compiler to ignore this.

Comment: Have you tried with a less $variable instead of css variable?

Answer (score 1):

SASS attempts to compile the styles with a [SASS-specific rgba() function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules#rgb). However, [rgba() is also a native CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba()), so you can use string interpolation to bypass the SASS function.

```
:root {
    --bg-color: 50, 50, 50, 0.5;
}

.container {
    /* This is valid CSS, but will fail in a scss compilation */
    background: rgba(var(--bg-color));
    
    /* This is valid scss, and will generate the CSS above */
    background: #{'rgba(var(--bg-color))'};
}
```

Taken from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47625605/1280867).