# CSS variable not working within SCSS when I use var and rgba

Tags: sass, css-variables

I have searched around for this but none seems to work.

I am working on Angular and have my scss variables on the root file, styles.scss in the :root pseudo-selector. The following works in my component scss;

```css
    :root {--color-primary-green:#00e676}

    background-color:var(--color-primary-green);
```

When I try to use rgba, the color disappears i.e

```css
    background-color: rgba(var(--color-primary-green), 0.5);
```

How can I go around this?

Comment: So what is —color-primary-green..? Is it actually an rgb?

Comment: I have edited to reflect the same

Comment: Yeah that won’t work in rgba.. nothing to do with Angular

Comment: I know there is nothing do with Angular @MikeOne, the reason I asked is basically to get views on how I can represent the styles on the global scope and access them as variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I apply opacity to a CSS color variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010597/how-do-i-apply-opacity-to-a-css-color-variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your style variables file include both the hex and rgba versions of your colours. Then you can use the rgb value when it is required.

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: #2dd36f;
  --color-primary-rgb: 45, 211, 111;
}

.hex-bg {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.rgba-bg {
  background-color: rgba(var(--color-primary-rgb), 0.5);
}

div {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-bg">
  background with hex value
</div>

<div class="rgba-bg">
  background with rgba value
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

First, to define the color for a CSS property it must be the same [color type format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).

If you use VSCode it will be easy to switch between different color types with [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbugh.change-color-format).