# How to combine LESS color functions and CSS Variables?

Tags: css, less, css-variables

In my project I have a CSS custom variables like this:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #e04c4c;
  --secondary-color: #2c2c5e;
  --text-color: #d67900; 
}
```

In my LESS files  I have used LESS color functions to get more colors base on its primary and secondary. This is how its look like:

```
.component1 {
  background: darken(--primary-color, 10%);
}

.component2 {
  background: lighten(--secondary-color, 5%);
}
```

But when I compile this, it gives an error like this?

> // Undefined_methodError: error evaluating function `darken`: //
> Object # has no method 'toHSL'

When googling I found a [solution](https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/how-to-combine-sass-color-functions-and-css-variables) for SASS, but not for LESS.

Can anybody tell me is there any possible workaround for this particular case?

Thank you.

Comment: Your [issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3537) on the Less/Less.js Git repo was answered: "Less runs at compile-time, not run-time (typically), and `--primary-color` is not a valid Less variable." See the posted [response](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3537) for a workaround.

Comment: @charles, yes it is. but in  this case I can't use less variable like that (in response). I have difined my theme colors dynamically and created CSS varibles to store them in main index page. Then I need to get those colors into `Less` like this `@primary-color : var(--primary-color)`. Its ok. but in LESS functions its not working. Eg. `color : lighten(@primary-color, 10%)`.

Comment: Less won't resolve the CSS variable so that approach won't work. If you can edit the selector from `:root` to `:root, .root` (or something similar), you can try this approach: `color: lighten(.root()[--primary-color], 10%);`.

Comment: @charles, Thank you for your suggestion. Can you elaborate your suggestion? Its good if you can create an answer for it. Thank you.

Comment: I just realized that you wrote: "...store them in main index page." If that means an internal stylesheet (i.e., inside a `<style>` tag in an HTML document) then my suggestion above will not work. Is that the case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010597/how-do-i-apply-opacity-to-a-css-color-variable