# Is there a way to type check CSS custom properties (aka CSS variables)?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I'm considering replacing SCSS variables (i.e. `$someValue`) with CSS custom properties (e.g. `var(--someValue)`) in an attempt to both allow for a little more flexibility in the form of theming and context-specific overrides, and to make the devtools in browsers a little more usable. Eventually, I'd potentially like to dump SCSS variables entirely just to simplify the development stack.

However, I've noticed that unlike SCSS variables, CSS custom properties are entirely un-checked, and typos are a thing. I've had code break in confusing ways because a typo was made either setting a CSS custom property, or using it in an expression - after all, CSS is very lenient using un-set or invalidly set CSS properties.

Since CSS custom properties aren't exactly new at this point, I thought I'd be able to find some webpack plugin or other solution to add basic typechecking to CSS properties, but I can't seem to find any.  Ideally, I'd like to require all CSS custom properties to be declared in some fashion, including something like a type for its contents (to ensure that e.g. variables are consistently used as a dimensionless vs. dimension-full value vs. color, etc), but even just a tool or technique to detect typos would catch real errors.  However, I've been unable to find anything like this, either as a build tool, or SASS plugin.

How can I protect myself from simple oversights when using CSS custom properties, e.g. detect that a property set as `--someValue: 13px` is never used or conversely that a reference `var(--someValue)` appears to have no matching assignments?

Comment: Great question, although since I can't imagine doing this without a tool it sorta risks getting closed as as a tool recommendation question. It's worth noting that custom properties are typeless by design, since having typos and even "syntax errors" for values is an intentional design decision, enabling techniques such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265350). Such a tool you're looking for would probably need to assume that you will never use custom properties this way, unless you're content with simple checks like the "unused property" ones you mention.

Comment: It might be the right direction to look into popular linters like [stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint) which already has a bunch of rules and `supports plugins so you can create your own rules or make use of plugins written by the community`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the new [`@property`](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-properties-values-api-1/#at-property-rule) rule you can almost have what you want since it will allow to define the type for your variables.

Example:

```css
@property --primary-color {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: blue;
}

.box {
  --primary-color: red; /* this one is valid */
  background:var(--primary-color);
  height:100px;
}

.box-alt {
  --primary-color:10px; /* this one is invalid and will fall to the intial-value */
  background:var(--primary-color);
  border:var(--primary-color) solid green; /* it won't be used here even if contain pixel */
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box-alt"></div>
```

You need to run the above on Chrome or Edge (Firefox still doesn't support this). As you can see, using pixel value is not allowed here since we specified the type to be `<color>`.

Actually the dev tool will show you nothing but this will probably change in the future to get some warning. In the meantime, you can rely on the initial value that will get used when the custom property is either not defined or defined with an invalid value.

Comment: Adding the link to [can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property), to check quicker if FF supports this already.

Answer (score -1):

another way to simply allow all the vars (for those who don't need a name/value check):

```js
import 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  interface CSSProperties extends Record<`--${string}`, any> {}
}
```