# CSS - pass rgb inside rgba

Tags: html, css

how to pass color `rgb` inside `rgba` to decrease opacity?

```css
:root {
  --bg: rgb(84, 15, 84);
}

p {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hello world
</p>
```

I want to pass the `--bg` variable inside `rgba` so I can decrease the opacity without touching touching the `--bg` variable.

I have tried:

```
background-color: rgba( var(--bg), 0.4 );
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265350/13405106

Comment: You should use only the numbers of rgb in the var.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010597/how-do-i-apply-opacity-to-a-css-color-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --bg: 84, 15, 84;
}

p {
  background-color: rgba(var(--bg),0.4);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hello world
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `rgb` extension while passing it to the variable like so.

```css
:root {
  --bg: 84, 15, 84;
}

p {
  background-color: rgba(var(--bg), 0.4);
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<p>
  hello world
</p>
```