# SASS variable in function is not a colour

Tags: css, sass

I have a CSS var that is defined in the root as a HEX, this is unchangeable.

```
--blue: ##0000FF
```

I'd like to use this variable to create an opacity, like this:

```
color: rgba(var(--blue), 0.1)
```

This won't work as `--blue` is a HEX so I use a function like this to convert it:

```
@function hex-to-rgb($hex) {
  @return red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex)
}
```

and I then try:

```
color: rgba(hex-to-rgb(var(--blue)), 0.1)
```

However I'm getting the error `$color: var(--blue) is not a color`

I'm also trying transparentize and other solutions but I keep on getting that the blue variable isn't a colour...

Is there a way of making this work?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330997/8620333