# How to use predefined hexadecimal css color variable in scss rgba with opacity?

Tags: css, sass, hex, rgb, css-variables

**What I have?**

An scss file with pre-defined colors, which are css variables saved as hex color codes (e.g. `--error-color: #B42318;`).

I now want to use this `--error-color` variable within an `rgba` function (because I want to use it in a `linear-gradient`). E.g. like this: `rgba(var(--error-color), 1)`). Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

**What I've noticed:**

When I use the following HTML:

```
<div class="box color1">1</div>
<div class="box color2">2</div>
<div class="box color3">3</div>
<div class="box color4">4</div>
<div class="box color5">5</div>
```

With the following SCSS file:

```
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  --color-as-rgb: 180,35,24;
  --color-as-hex: #B42318;
}

.color1 { background-color: var(--color-as-hex); }
.color2 { background-color: rgba(#B42318, 1); }
.color3 { background-color: rgba(180,35,24, 1); }
.color4 { background-color: rgba(var(--color-as-hex), 1); }
.color5 { background-color: rgba(var(--color-as-rgb), 1); }
```

Only #4, which is exactly what I want in my case, doesn't work as intended..

[image]

Is there a way to convert a hexadecimal color to a comma-separated RGB during compilation of the scss? Or any kind of alternative so I can use my existing hexadecimal css variables with an opacity?

**Two things I've tried (without success):**

Convert the css variable to a scss variable, and try to use that in the `rgba`, which will have a similar result as #4.

```
.color6 {
  $color-as-hex: var(--color-as-hex);
  background-color: rgba($color-as-hex, 1);
}
```

Use `transparentize` instead of `rgba`, but it seems to be even more limited and actually gives scss compilation errors:

```
.color7a { background-color: transparentize(#B42318, 0); } /* Works hard-coded without css variable */
.color7b { background-color: transparentize(180,35,24, 0); } /* SassError: Only 2 arguments allowed, but 4 were passed. */
.color7c { background-color: transparentize(var(--color-as-hex), 0); } /* SassError: $color: var(--color-as-hex) is not a color. */
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330997/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Tyvm! Got a solution based on your answer (which I've added to the bottom of my closed answer in case anyone else comes across it).

Comment: don't add the solution to your question but rather upvote the answer if it's useful.