# CSS background-color value with var(--hexcode) and additional alpha value

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a 2px border and transparent background. And I want to make the background-color become semi-transparent when hover, the hex color code is store in a var() with the name --hexcode. The problem I facing is how to add alpha value after the var() value

```css
:root {
  --hexcode: #fff;
}

.stroke-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}

.stroke-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--hexcode) + '88';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="stroke-btn">Click Me<button>
```

Comment: The equivalent of `rgba(256,256,256,.88)` is `#ffffffe0` (which you can establish via the browser's color inspector). However, there doesn't seem to be a way to tack this onto the end of your custom property. In any case, you'd have to change the custom property to `#ffffff` for it to work, or you'd have to tack on `fffe0` to the end. But I can't figure out any way to tack that on to the end of `var(--hexcode)`. I've tried all sorts of combinations, such as `var(--hexcode)fffe0` etc., but none of them worked. Interested to know if there is a way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330997/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
.stroke-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(var(--hexcode), 0.88);
}
```

If that doesn't work, then use this to define your `var`:

```
:root {
    --hexcode : 255, 255, 255;
}
```

Comment: i had thought of this, but i have a long list of hexcode to convert to rgb, all existing style that use hexcode, i have to change it to rgba(var(--otherhex)). that will be too much.

Comment: @mok_ku it would only take a couple of minutes to write a script to convert all your hex values into rgb values. see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/3163495

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in hex format with the alpha included.

```css
:root {
  --red-50: #ff00007f;
  --blue-50: #0000ff7f;
}

body {
  background: #888;
}

.stroke-btn {
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px
}

.stroke-btn.red:hover {
  background-color: var(--red-50);
}
.stroke-btn.blue:hover {
  background-color: var(--blue-50);
}
```

```html
<button class="stroke-btn red">Click Me</button>
<button class="stroke-btn blue">Click Me</button>
```